# Xinput.h: No such file or directory

Tags: filenotfoundexception, xbox, xinput

I'm trying to get input from an xbox controller, I went to this page:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26949/Xbox-360-Controller-Input-in-C-with-XInput

and I'm just test running his source, good thing I did because it found an error:

```
C:\Users\me;)\Desktop\XBOX360Test\XBOX360Test\CXBOXController.h|9|fatal error: Xinput.h:  No such file or directory|
```

Can I don't know what the issue is, doesn't Xinput ship with windows?

Comment: If you need more context to help answer, I can definitely post some. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm late I know, but I get the same error.
Opening the project in Visual Studio works fine, but compiling with gcc doesn't. Seems like the compiler of VS knows more than gcc and you need to compile it with that one. Here's how:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639(v=vs.80).aspx